# TextField Events

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to update an array through a textfield change. 
For example, textfield contain he string = "ABC" and the array to be updated is {"ABC","DEF","GHI"}.

I wrote the following function in angularJS:

```
$scope.aliasChanged = function(newVal,oldFieldValue)
{
            if($scope.ConfigJSON)
            {

                if($scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.indexOf(oldFieldValue) > -1)
                {
                    $scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.splice($scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.indexOf(oldFieldValue),1);
                    $scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.push(newVal)
                }

            }
        }
```

Corresponding html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row.alias"                               
ng-focus='oldFieldValue=row.alias'
ng-change="aliasChanged(row.alias,oldFieldValue)">
```

Now if there's a single edit(just one key press, everything works fine). "ABC" is removed from the array and "AB" is added. But if multiple keystrokes are logged in at a time, the code breaks. "ABC" is removed "AB" is added. But "AB" is not removed and "A" is not added. I guess the array was under write-lock by the first fucntion call when 'C' was being deleted. ANy clues how to achieve my target ?

Comment: `and the array to be updated is {"ABC","DEF","GHI"}.` This is not `array`

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch your array to an object instead? That way you can look up the property and change its value for each keystroke.

```
$scope.aliasChanged = function(key,newValue)
  {
    if($scope.ConfigJSON)
    {
        if($scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields[key])
        {

            $scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields[key] = newValue;
            //$scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.splice($scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.indexOf(oldFieldValue),1);
            //$scope.ConfigJSON.LogProcessing.Fields.push(newVal)
        }

    }
  }
```

And the call in the html would look like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row.alias"    
ng-change="aliasChanged('ABC', row.alias)">
```

You could always convert this object back into an array format if you really need an array when you submit the form (or whatever action you are doing afterwards).

http://plnkr.co/edit/o59oJgxpBIklag0Vca5e?p=preview